# Installshield c# application with local database didnt work

Tags: c#, database, local, installshield

i have developed a `c#` application including a local database.
When i create a `installshield` setup and install the application, the application reads the data correctly from database but it is not possible to insert or update data into the database.

I get the error message that the database is "readonly".

The database is in the installation folder. When i install the database in `AppData` folder, then the application didn't work because the application search the database in the install folder.

How can i solve this problem?

Hope some guys can help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the `app.config` connectionString to point to the `AppData` folder.
Here's an example:

[How to use Application Data in an (App.config) connectionString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243731/how-to-use-application-data-in-an-app-config-connectionstring)