# C# connection string to application data folder

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

I'm having a problem with my local database file `.mdf`. After create my setup project, I read on internet that my `.mdf` files should be in the User's application data folder, that's why I'm having permissions error on my `.mdf` files. So, in the project setup, I right click and add a special folder "User´s Application Data Folder" and drag my `.mdf` files there.

If this will create a folder on the Windows app data of the client, with my database files, what should be my connection string?

Right now is this way:

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseIris.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

Comment: It is not clear if you are using a config file to store your connectionstring or if you set this string by code. Could you explain it better?

Comment: Im using by code. On the App.config file on the visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/4243751/3043

Which suggests doing it like this:

```
connectionString="..;AttachDbFilename=|%AppData%|\DatabaseIris.mdf;.." />
```

Comment: This gives me a error. Invalid value for para 'attachdbfilename

Comment: @Brugo did you read the _whole_ answer, specifically the part that replaces `%AppData%` with the special folder name - does the file actually exist in that folder?

Comment: Sry my friend. I dont know how to put this in my connection string. This line of code is all the visual studio give me about my connection string. Can you help me do this?